# Difference between const auto * and const auto?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, constants, auto

I have this code:

```
const int a = 10;
const auto *b = &a; //0x9ffe34
const auto c = &a; //0x9ffe34

int z = 20;
b = &z; //0x9ffe38
//c = &z; //[Error] assignment of read-only variable 'c'
```

Why can you assign a new address to `b` and not to `c`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`b` will be deduced as `const int*`, which means a **non-const** pointer pointing to `const int`, so it's fine to change the value of `b` itself.

`c` will be deduced as `const int * const`, which means a **const** pointer pointing to `const int`, so you couldn't change the value of `c` itself.

**Explanation**

For this case [auto specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) will use the rules for [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts).

> Once the type of the initializer has been determined, the compiler determines the type that will replace the keyword auto using the rules for template argument deduction from a function call.

For `const auto *b = &a;`, and `&a` is `const int*`, then `auto` will be replaced as `int`, then `b` will be a `const int*`.

For `const auto c = &a;`, `auto` will be replaced as `const int*`, then `c` will be a `const int* const`. Note the `const` is the qualifier on `c` itself in `const auto c`.

Comment: How come? I mean, what the difference between withing the * declarator and without it.

Comment: This is what I suspected also, but I am having a hard time finding the part of the standard that indicates this behaviour.

Comment: for more understanding read this http://codeketchup.blogspot.sg/2013/03/type-of-consent-pointers-in-c.html

Comment: @DirtyOleg I added some explanations.

Comment: @songyuanyao almost understood, but how do you know the const is bound to c not to auto?

Comment: @DirtyOleg It'll be deduced independently, and the deduced result should not change. For example, if `auto` is deduced as `int*`, then the combined result will be `int* const`, it won't change from `int*` to `const int*`.

Comment: @songyuanyao  for my understanding now, &a will give us const int *. const auto *b declare b is a pointer point to a const auto-type(auto give us const int *, but we already know b is point to a const, so the actual deduced type is int), whereas const auto c declaring c is a const auto-type, so combined them, c should be const int* const

Comment: `const auto c` means the `const` applies to `c`  . `const auto *b` means the `const` applies to `*b`.

Comment: @DirtyOleg Sorry can't get what you mean, shouldn't `c` be `const int* const`?

Comment: ok, what i think is, const auto *b is like const int *b means b is a pointer pointing to a constant, whose type are deduced by auto. for this example, &a give us const int *,mean a pointer to a constant int. for b, auto deduce int, and  the statement become const int *b, for c, auto deduce const int* and the statement become const int * const c(because const auto c means c is a const variable with a "auto" or deduced type)   don't know If I made myself clear(#ﾟДﾟ)

Comment: @DirtyOleg "const auto c means c is a const variable with a "auto" or deduced type", yes I think it's clear.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks a lot